# Why can't pass this servlet response data to App Engine jsp?

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

Ok, I am using java Google app engine. I got a servlet "ConversationServlet.java"

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
 String para=req.getParameter("param");
 String data=getDatafromDB(para);
 //Now I want to pass this data to conversationbase.jsp
 req.setAttribute("conversationOfLesson", data);
            try {
                req.getRequestDispatcher("conversationbase.jsp").forward(req, resp);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

In conversationbase.jsp

```
<body>
<%=request.getAttribute("conversationOfLesson") %>
</body>
```

but when open conversationbase.jsp, it showed "`null`"

Then I tried

```
<body>
${conversationOfLesson}
</body>
```

but when open conversationbase.jsp, it showed nothing.

How to fix this error?

Comment: It is Not part of a form

Comment: Please debug and look what is data?

Comment: If you share where do you call servlet it will be excellent ))

Answer (score 0):

When `conversationbase.jsp` shows "null", it mean, "`conversationOfLesson`" attribute value is set as `null`. You can double check it by adding log statements in the "ConversationServlet" servlet file.

I have deployed [sample app](https://example-for-others.appspot.com/hello?param=test) with the same logic.:) If you remove the param, JSP will render with `null`.